# Google Analytics code installation failure on static github page

Tags: html, google-analytics, github-pages

I'm new to GA4 and have spent several hours trying to get this work on my own. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple.
I have made the simplest "Hello World" static site via github.[static site link](https://tomthomas.github.io/Boxsports/)
I made an account in GA4 and Tag Manager and have been going back and forth between them to get the snippet fire back to Google.
Tried it with just the GA4 snippet and then with just the Tag Manager one and then with both.
Yet my GA4 account still says that

> Data collection isn’t active for your website. If you installed tags
> more than 48 hours ago, make sure that they are set up correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-K4JYTJBZT9"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'G-K4JYTJBZT9');
    </script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MLBVL3Z');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GFG</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MLBVL3Z"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <h1>Hello World this is my first web page.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Can someone help please.
Is my index.html not created accurately?
Am I missing some step within GA4. I thought all I had to do was put in this code beneath the head and body and it would reflect in the data collected.

thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set this up correctly. I'd take a look at your Google Analytics property and check that your website's URL (https://tomthomas.github.io/Boxsports/) is connected as a data stream. Good luck!